# How to compute the number of 'True' valued matrices in a tensor?

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow2.0, tensor

In the below tensor of dimension (5,1,5,5), I want to calculate the number of 5*5(innermost) Boolean matrices where all the values are 'True'.
For example,

```
tf.constant([
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
   [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]], 
    
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  False],
   [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  False,  True,  True,  True]]],
            
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
   [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  False,  True,  False,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]],
 
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]],
             
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]],
 
 ])
```

In the above tensor, there are total of 5 innermost matrices with dimension 5 by 5. Out of them 3 matrices contain both 'False' and 'True' values whereas the last 2 matrices contain only 'True' values. I need to compute the ratio of total number of matrices with only 'True' values to that of total number of matrices with both 'True' and 'False' values. In this case it would be :
total number of matrices with only 'True' values / Total number of matrices = 2/5

How can I compute this ?
One way, I can think of is to use tf.squeeze() to remove the 1 dimension and then convert it into numpy array and then loop through it. However, this is not the optimized way to do it. I want to do it using tensorflow (with tensor datatype and not numpy array) as this needs to be extremely time efficient.

Further, I also want to compute the ratio of total number of innermost rows where all values are 'True' to that of total number of rows. For example, in our case it would be :
total number of rows with only 'True' values / total number of rows = 16/25.
This too, needs to be using tensor and highly time-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need **tf.reduce_all** .

```
import tensorflow as tf
temp_tesnor = tf.constant([
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
   [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]], 
    
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  False],
   [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  False,  True,  True,  True]]],
            
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
   [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  False,  True,  False,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]],
 
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]],
             
 [[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]],
 
 ])

temp_tesnor.shape # TensorShape([5, 1, 5, 5])
```

Then reduce the tensor where the dimension is 1.

```
temp_tesnor = tf.squeeze(temp_tesnor, axis = [1])
temp_tesnor.shape # TensorShape([5, 5, 5])
```

**Result for query1**

```
result1 = 0
for i in temp_tesnor:
    if tf.reduce_all(i):
        result1 += 1
print(result1)  # prints 2 . Divide here with your first dimension. here it is 5.
```

**Result for query2**

```
result2 = 0
for inner_tensor in temp_tesnor:
    for i in inner_tensor:
        if tf.reduce_all(i):
            result2 += 1
print(result2) # prints 16 . divide here by multiplication of dimension 
#of last two axis . here it is 5*5 = 25
```

This is all done in tensorflow.